# Angular Momentum and Spherical Top

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, eigenvalue

The Schrödinger equation for 2 nuclei at fixed distance $R$ can be transformed to relative and centre of mass coordinates and gives rise to the Eigenvalue problem $$\frac{{J}^2 \Psi_{jm}}{2\mu R^2} = E \Psi_{jm} \tag{1}$$
where the eigenfunctions are labeled by two quantum numbers $j$ and $m$ for total angular momentum with eigenvalue $j(j+1)$ and its projection $m$ onto the $z$-axis taking values $-j,-j+1,...,j-1,j$. This equation assumes the nuclei being infinitely small and the rotation takes place about either of the two choices for the rotation axes with moment of inertia $I_x=I_y=\mu R^2$ (reduced mass $\mu$). The rotation about the figure axis is not possible (well maybe it is? see below...), but the moment of inertia here is $I_z=0$. Let's stop here and consider the more general symmetric top molecule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor).

It arises when the above equation is written more generally for different moment of inertias about each of the principal axes and the kinetic energy equation becomes
$$\left(\frac{P_x^2}{2I_x} + \frac{P_y^2}{2I_y} + \frac{P_z^2}{2I_z}\right) \Psi = E \Psi \, .$$
If $I_x=I_y$ then this equation can be written as
$$\left(\frac{P^2}{2I_x} + \left(\frac{1}{2I_z} - \frac{1}{2I_x} \right)P_z^2\right) \Psi_{jmk} = E \Psi_{jmk} \tag{2} \, .$$

For a prolate symmetric top $I_z \ll I_x$ (e.g. for an electron cloud of a diatomic molecule), so let's assume it is close to $0$. This case should be equivalent to (1), but what happens in the limit $I_z \rightarrow 0$? Is this divergent contribution absorbed in $E$, because the equation doesn't make sense like this while it should be equivalent to (1) at the same time.

(2) is an equation written with respect to the principal axes system i.e. for a molecule fixed reference frame. Typically the projection onto the internuclear axis in the molecule fixed frame is not labeled $m$ but $k$. This is because when transforming the space fixed angular momentum operators $J$ - written in terms of Euler angles - from the space fixed to the molecule fixed frame (angular momentum already named $P$ as in (2)), these two sets of operators commute (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Properties_of_the_Wigner_D-matrix). Therefore they can be diagonalized simultaneously with $(P_z,k)$ and $(J_z,m)$ being good quantum numbers. The range of $k$ and $m$ are the same because $J^2=P^2$ so their absolute angular momenta $j(j+1)$ are the same (as they should be if angular momentum is conserved).

What bothers me though is why this really crucial feature is not captured nor even ever discussed in the context of solving (1). It is always stated that there is a $(2j+1)$-fold degeneracy for a given eigenvalue, but the symmetric tops shows there really is a $2(2j+1)$-fold degeneracy if $k\neq 0$ even if $I_z$ is very small. What's the physical background that gets lost in (1)? If $I_z=0$ does this imply that $k$ has to be zero as well? If so, why?